# How to detect that file dialog has been created using GetOpenFileName?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-vista, getopenfilename

I take a part in developing of namespace shell extension([NSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) containing file list from some folders. I have some problems with Open file dialog (OFD) created with the flag `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT` on Window Vista.

If application uses OFD created using `IFileOpenDialog` my NSE works fine. 
If application uses OFD created using `GetOpenFileName` and user selects some files then he gets an incorrect result because this function returns the string:

```
<Folder name>\0<File name 1>\0<File name2>\0\0
```

I must use single select mode in my NSE if application uses OFD created using `GetOpenFileName`.

### The question is:

Is here is any way to detect in my NSE that OFD has been created using `GetOpenFileName`?

Comment: You can't detect this. It sounds as though you want to change the behaviour of the file dialog rather than fix the bugs in your NSE. People write software the use multi-select file dialogs because they, er, want to select multiple files. Trying to block that is exceptionally user-hostile.

Comment: I've tested OFD created using GetOpenFileName on my NSE and Windows Search result and got same bugs. I think, my NSE returns correct data but GetOpenFileName can't process it and can't put correct file names (with subfolders) into result string. I don't want to change the behaviour of OFD but if it returns incorrect file names user will get an error "File not found". Can I use the next way: try to get IFileOpenDialog from IShellBrowser and if this attempt is successfully then OFD has been created using IFileOpenDialog otherwise using GetOpenFileName. But I am not sure it is possibly.

Comment: That's not an incorrect result that's how windows OFD delimits multiple selected files.

Comment: There must be the following result: <Folder name>\0<File name 1>\0<Subfolder 1\File name2>\0<Folder name>\0<Subfolder 2\File name 3>\0\0. OFD created with IFileOpenDialog returns correct result in IShellItemArray

Answer (score 0):

The old GetOpenFileName dialog was never designed to handle multiple files in different parent folders.

Trying to fix this by detecting the type of open dialog used is wrong and GetOpenFileName might just be a wrapper on top of the new interface.

When your IShellFolder::EnumObjects method is called, look for the `SHCONTF_FLATLIST` flag. If the flag is not set then you should revert to some type of simple mode where all items have the same parent. I realize that this is not exactly what the flag is for but it is probably the best non-hacky solution.